# How to track if user is logged in with HTTP-only cookie in VUE SPA client with Pinia store, and Api, JWT?

Tags: jwt, vuejs3, authorization, single-page-application

after searching all over the web I must ask, how  to get Vue client app to know when user is logged in when authenticated with HTTP-only cookie. Calls to API with Axios!

**This is how it goes:**
Client makes a login request to Node Express **API**, and receives an **HTTP-only** cookie if everything is valid. The cookie is automatically set and included in every succeeding AXIOS call to the server.
Along with the cookie, every Server request response is structured like this

```
{
 status:{
 error:false (or true),
 msg:''
 }
 data:{some data}
}
```

The question is how to track user logged in state when there's no access to the Http-only cookie ??
How would a router know that user has a bad cookie(JWT) and logout user, redirect where it needs??How would a server order a client to remove the cookie in any bad case and logout user??

Should I **set the global state variable** userLogged = ref(true) **automaticaly after Loggin request** response is received (when status is success)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to track a global state but ideally you want to use a LIB that is compatible with your authentication service and provides you with various auth state events that can be used to set the value of your global state bool value.

It can become complex to build something your self that covers all cases.

Life is easier if you are working with OAuth standards because there are many OAuth standard libs out there such as [oidc-client-ts](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts) that would give you various events to work with such as `UserLoaded` or `SignedIn` you can use to set the value to `true` and `UserSignedOut` or `UserUnloaded` to set it to `false`.

So find out what standard you are using, find a lib for it.
Tell us here what your using for your auth provider so more specific help can be given from other users.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time and answer! Actually, I'm not using any AUTH provider. Just a simple login authentication with MYSQL DB. I'm building a project for an entry position portfolio, nothing overly complicated. For now, I have a login route that returns user public data if  authenticated, then a userLogged bool property in Pinia state is set to true. There's a Logout route that removes httpOnly cookie , and than userLogged is set to false, user data set to empty object.

Comment: I do have a concept for cases like these where you don't have intelligence on the validity of a token and have to use a level of assumption instead, I will have to come back to you on this a bit later on a small workaround, stuck for time right this moment.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with tokens anyway, once they are compromised they can't be invalidated I guess.